# Why 'VIRT' is less than 'RES' in top

Tags: python, memory

I have running a python script several days. And now found that it consume nearly all of physical memory. So I use top to inspect and found that it used 86.4% physical memory. A funny thing is that the **VIRT** was less than **RES**.

[image]

In my opinion, **RES** represents non-swapped physical memory. **VIRT** indicates the total amount of virtual memory used by the task.

In what situation, the physical memory used would be greater than virtual memory used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In top (and ps) the unit of VIRT and RES is KiB where no prefix is printed. Your process has mapped ~6GB virtual memory and ~3GB physical.

Comment: I think you meant suffix?